# How to have changes made in media library to be reflected on posts/pages

Tags: media-library

I have recently invested a bunch of hours updating the alt text of all the images in a media library, only to realise that the changes are not reflected on posts/pages.

Whoops!

Is there any way to force these changes across? Or have I no choice but to edit each page manually?

Hope someone has good news for me!

Thanks

Comment: You have to edit your template file that displays those images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image is the featured image or some image inserted via a shortcode, then those changes will reflect automatically(if they don't, it's your theme's fault, you'll have to edit your theme)

If the image is inserted into the post content, yes you'll have to go through each page/post & manually do the changes. Though updating them in media library assures that they will be inserted right the next time you insert the same images.

Answer (score 0):

If the images are inserted in the WYSIWYG editor then alt texts and such won't be updated automatically.
Then you probably have to edit them manually.

If they are outside the editor then your template should pick up the changes.